# Resources to make 8-bit computer like this one?

Tags: microcontroller

I am 15 years old and love electronics. I made very basic circuits using breadboard and basic components. I want to build 8-bit Computer like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYvr0b8jqbg 
which includes Graphics Processor, Central Processing Unit.

What are some resources to make this kind of computer?  or tell me what should I search on google to make this kind of computer as shown in the video.
At this age I have lots  of time and I am ready to do a lot of hard work.

If the question is too broad then please suggest me some websites where I can read about collection of resources like books, videos etc. to make 8-bit computer.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered here, so expect your question to be closed.

Comment: Since you've asked and want to learn, I've done a quick google search and found someone who did what you are asking about.  This person documented the whole thing online, and provides all the source code.  Check here:  http://blog.atmel.com/2015/04/08/building-a-minimal-8-bit-microcomputer-with-avr/

Comment: I'm extrememly bias because Yale Patt was my professor for the more advanced class in this subject. However his book "Introduction to Computing Systems: From bits & gates to C & beyond" does still cover the basics of how computers work. But to get to the point where you've actually created the architecture like in that video... expect it to take about 1-2 years min.

Comment: @user1444692 On the other hand, if you see yourself getting a career in computer programming, microcontroller/embedded system programming, or similar field, those two years can be of tremendous assistance later on. Furthermore, you'll actually know something about practical issues that the experts in the field face. So if you think you're interested, dig in!

Comment: @AndrejaKo I am so much interested in this field and ready to dig in.

Comment: The video you linked to goes into much more depth than the Arduino based system I linked to, but I think it would help you to start off relatively easy before moving up to a full bore CPU/GPU in TTL.

Comment: I read a book called "But How Do it Know" by J. Clark Scott. It is a very good book and starts from the ground up (gates and binary) to a fully functioning computer. The beginning teaches you the basics about gates. The rest(most of the book) shows you how to build an 8 bit computer from scratch. Some people say that it skips over some information while explaining, but it is still easy to understand. It is very simple(compared to a few other books) but it still is a very concise and complete guide to building a fully functioning computer. You don't need any background info to read it.

Comment: A follow up of my last comment: Here is an unofficial video(not made by the author) that highlights a few of the things the book covers. Bear in mind that the book teaches you more than the video and that the book explains each piece of the computer in a more "in-depth" way. Here is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNN_tTXABUA

Comment: @zack1544 Is the book you mentioned also tell me about implementing these stuffs.

Comment: What do you mean @user1444692 when you say implementing the stuff in the book? Are you asking if the book teaches you how to combine and implement multiple parts to build a computer?

Comment: No!, I got my answer by the end of video you mentioned. Thanks for mentioning video.

Comment: And also if you read the book I mentioned or learn anything about building a computer(gates, binary etc.) from any source, I recommend using a logic circuit simulator to test out different parts and circuits in the books/resources. After you get the hand of using the simulator and you have enough knowledge you can test out your own circuits. A free simulator called Logisim is good enough for your needs. It is completely free and you can find videos about using the simulator online. I recommend reading about digital logic(from any source or the boom I mentioned) before (cont. in next comment)

Comment: embarking on the task of making something on a simulator, as the simulator may seem overwhelming at first. There are many tutorials about logisim on youtube. There are also download instructions on the website: http://www.cburch.com/logisim/download.html                           You need Java 5 or later to run it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend beginning with reading up on logic gates and binary. Challenge yourself to create a full binary adder circuit and a binary decoder circuit to start with. You can use a simple online logic simulator to begin with such as logic.ly or circuitlab.com - please note that these do not support saving so after your first experiments it may be a good idea to move on to a different simulation software.

There are plentiful resources online to begin learnining about logic ciruits, and soon you'll be able to create more complex and cool things. It's key to learn about things like SR latches and JK flip flops.

Once you've taught yourself a bit of the logic theory, you can start experimenting with physically building them! Get hold of some logic chips and see if you can use a breadboard to create the logic circuits you simulated and learnt about. Use buttons as inputs and LEDs as your outputs.

Most of all, there can be a few 'dry' parts about learning about digital logic however the overall experience can be very satisfying and enjoyable. Have fun with it!

Comment: This is a good recommendation, follow it. Sure a binary adder does not sound as fancy as a Computer but it is a much better place to start. A suggestion for a more practical project as soon as you have learned the basics: a digital clock (without using a microController of course). Enjoy electronics !